# My binary search will find only the element that is located in the middle of the array

Tags: c#, binary-search

So I'm trying to make a binary search to find out by the surname but my code will only find if the element I search is the one located in the middle of the arrays, otherwise it will freeze and crash, does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

```
      private int binarySearch(string surnameSearched)
    {
        int start = 0;
        int end = direcTable.Length - 1;
        bool found = false;
        bool allListSearched = false;
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        while ((!found) && (!allListSearched))
        {
            lvDirectory.Items.Clear();
            if (String.Compare(direcTable[mid].surname, surnameSearched, true) == 0)
            {
                found = true;
            }
            else if (start > end)
            {
                allListSearched = true;
            }
            else if (String.Compare(direcTable[mid].surname, surnameSearched) < 0)
            {
                end = mid - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                start = mid + 1;
            }
        }
        if (found)
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
            lvi.Text = direcTable[mid].extCode;
            lvi.SubItems.Add(direcTable[mid].forename);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(direcTable[mid].surname);
            lvDirectory.Items.Add(lvi);
            return (mid);

        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
```

Comment: You are never changing `mid` ie, the element you are looking at.

Comment: And what do you mean by "freeze and crash"? Any error message? Especially if you attach a debugger it should give you some error message

Comment: Is this purely for studying? Because we already have `Array.BinarySearch`

Comment: And as you are not changing `mid` also `start` and `end` won't change their values, thus you are stuck in an infinite loop, because `allListsSearched` can never get true

Comment: The *freeze* part is probably because the loop does never end and is executed in never-ending loop. The only reason to crash is `lvDirectory.Items.Clear();` and that is only when the `lvDirectory` is a graphics control. Sometimes when you call too many times operation it can cause problems. In this case I suppose it can be that the buffer for messages overflows. The messages are only added and not processed (function need to end and return the control to system to process messages). The `lvDirectory.Items.Clear();` should be outside of function or at least outside of while loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
       while (start < end)
       {
           int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
           lvDirectory.Items.Clear();
           if (String.Compare(direcTable[mid].surname, surnameSearched, true) == 0)
           {
               found = true;
           }
         
           if (String.Compare(direcTable[mid].surname, surnameSearched) < 0) // I Dont know on what bases your comparing in this If statment
           {
               end = mid ;
           }
           else
           {
               start = mid + 1;
           }
       }
```

Comment: `start + (end - start) / 2 == (start + end) / 2`